# Fetching Data From Prepared Statment In MySQLi And PHP

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

Hello I'm trying to fetch data from a prepared statement I wrote in PHP class and I've trying Alot please helop here is the PHP function in class members

```
public function Check() {
    $email = $this->getEmail();
    $user = $this->getUsername();
    $check = "SELECT firstName,lastName FROM members WHERE Email = ? AND Username = ? AND isActive = '1' ";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($check);
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $user);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetch();
}
```

And I want to get the data in a another page by including the class and create an object of it. here is my trying

```
<?php
                    $member = new Members();
                    $email = $member->setEmail(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars(trim($_GET['e']))));
                    $user = $member->setUsername(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars(trim($_GET['u']))));
                    if ($member->Check()) { echo $firstname." ".$lastname; } ?>
```

Please Help .. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to [bind the result variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php):

```
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($firstname, $lastname);
$stmt->fetch();
return array('firstname' => $firstname,'lastname' => $lastname);

$member = new Members();
$email = $member->setEmail(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars(trim($_GET['e']))));
$user = $member->setUsername(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars(trim($_GET['u']))));
$results = $member->Check();
if ($results) { echo $results['firstname']." ".$results['lastname']; } ?>
```

Comment: He is trying to access $firstname, $lastname but he forgot to bind the result to the variables.  What am i missing?